# Android dynamically load more rows in tableView

Tags: android, tableview

i have [this table with dynamical table-row adding](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/).

What I would like to do is not load the whole table because it sometimes has more than 10.000 rows.
I want to make a dynamically load the table is that possible?

Comment: 10000 rows of data from web or local database?

Comment: seems outdated, why would you use a tablelayout instead of a listview with each view repesenting a row? Use ListView with CursorAdapter

Comment: Local database what i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such thing, you must use `ListView` instead of `TableLayout`. Because with ListView, you can implement `onScrollListener`, with which you can load more iteam as and  when required.

Comment: but i have 7 cloums so i can't use listview

Comment: so you mean 7 columns are getting fitted well in TableLayout as compared to ListView?

Comment: sorry i don't understand :(

Comment: @David whatever number of columns you have. The UI which you can prepare with TableLayout can be achieved by using ListView itself, but if you use ListView then you have more privileges as compared to TableLayout.

Comment: hmm...okay but how to make a listview looks like a table?

Comment: It seems you don't know how to define custom adapter for ListView. Sorry I can't help here but Google can be your best friend!

Answer (score 0):

list view does have on scroll listener that will listen if you change focus of list view and you use simple logic to find when list view end is reached and respond accordingly